# Why do I still get errors using a switch statement with strings in Java SE7 on Lion?

Tags: netbeans, osx-lion, switch-statement, java-7

I am running Mac OSX lion and have a Java project in netbeans where I would like to use string switch statements. I downloaded and installed the OpenJDK7 and I think I have configured the project to use the Java 1.7 properly.

In the `Project Properties` I have set JDK 7 to the platform:
[image]

It is showing up as JDK 1.7 in the Libraries section in the Projects Window.

[image]

However, I still get a compilation error saying that switch with strings is not supported in 1.6

[image]

Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, I followed the very comprehensive tutorial from the netbeans website found here:
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jdk7.html

Specifically I had forgotten to set the `Sources/Binary Format` to JDK 7. You can do this in the bottom right of the `Sources` section of the `Project Properties` window.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything like Eclipse, the string case is a *language* feature, not a library feature. 
 Eclipse uses its own internal compiler by default and I suspect NetBeans is similar.

So you have to ensure you're using a JDK7 *compiler.* From a [cursory search](http://edu.netbeans.org/quicktour/jdks.html), the project settings should allow you to set an external compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 7.0.1 or greater?

> NetBeans 7.0.1 provide a hint if you have a chained if-else statement to take advantage of the JDK7 features. Have you downloaded it yet ? Check out screencast #35 highlighting Project Coin features in NetBeans. NetBeans 7.0.1 provide complete tooling around JDK7 and GlassFish 3.1.1 allow you to leverage JDK7 features in your Java EE 6 applications.

http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_168_string_switch_statement

Answer (score 0):

**Here are some steps:**

1. Select the project you want to change source settings for.
2. Got to `File` > `Project Properties`...
3. Select the `Sources` Category.
4. Change the `Source/Binary Format` dropdown to whatever format you want to use.

Viola!